# How to update a admin layout after creating Grid in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, grid-layout

I have created new Grid in custom module. But when it use it displays following error.

> Fatal error: Class 'XX_YY_Block_Adminhtml_Display' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491

**
I found some articles and it mentions to update `layout.xml`. But I could't found `layout.xml.` How to solve this problem

```
enter preformatted text here
```

Comment: it is clearly problem with your block `XX_YY_Block_Adminhtml_Display`.  check the class name and folder are correct.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. I have written a wrong class name. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is not related to `layout.xml`. It is clearly problem with your block `XX_YY_Block_Adminhtml_Display`. check the `class name` and `folder` are correct.